# Changing Connected Network in MacBook does not change the Network in iPhone Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

The settings in iPhone simulator does not have network options. But it takes the network automatically from the MacBook. However, when I connect the MacBook to a different network, the network change does not occur in the simulator.

I have tried:
1. Restarting the simulator
2. Restarting the MacBook

Has anyone faced similar issue and is there any resolution for this issue.

Comment: What do you mean "the network doesn't change"?

Comment: The connected Wifi Network does not change. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Not really. Where doesn't it change?

Comment: @paulw11 I am programmatically retrieving the network to which it is connected to. It always retrieves the old network connected to. The iPhone simulator does not display to which wifi network it is currently connected to.

Comment: Ok.  Your question would be clearer if you included the relevant code.  It may well be that this is one of those things that you will need to test on a real device.  The simulator is just a simulator.  It doesn't claim to be 100% the same as a real device.

Comment: I faced same problem, and its reason is using simulator, try to use real device and it will works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator is not connected to the Wifi network and knows nothing of the actual WiFi network; it simply inherits network connectivity from macOS.

You can run the simulator on a Mac that is connected by wired Ethernet and the simulator would still appear to be connected to a Wifi network from its point of view.

Code that depends on Wifi network details needs to run on a physical device, not the simulator.